# How to check the Field value Case

Tags: formula, validation

I wanna check the field value should be the Case sensitive. So, how to achieve this by using validation rule.

e.g John Milton Roa - Ltd.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more on your concern? Are you talking about the custom field on Case object and you want to compare it with some other field called as Title on Case?

Comment: I have created once text field and I would like to allow the text should be the title case(First letter should be capital letter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
REGEX(Name, ".*\\b\\p{Ll}.*" )
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using **REGEX** function. Something like this should do the work:

```
NOT(REGEX(Name, "([A-Z]([a-z])+\\s?)+"))
```

You can create your own regular expression to meet your needs (like ignoring special words - a, the, etc.). So this should be quite flexbile solution

Comment: is this work for this name : john Milton roa

Comment: Alex, It will not allow such value as it's not in Title Case. Please try me regex and you will see

Comment: can you let me know how to acieve by using regex?

Comment: Have you tried above code? It should work - I was testing it and it was fine. Please describe what issue do you have

Comment: it is not allowed the - so. i want to allow the hypen as well

Comment: Ok, to add hyphen as an additional word seperator and still force all words to be Title Case you can use following regex: NOT(REGEX(Name, "([A-Z]([a-z])+(\\s|-)?)+")). You can use generally available tools to build your own regex online like: https://regex101.com/ or http://www.regexr.com/. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Actually the name senario is more complicated. Markon Pvt. Ltd (corp). this should be acceptable. how to amend. sorry for too many queries.

Comment: Facebook - Pvt Ltd. this is not support.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below formula in validation condition:

```
IF(LEFT(fieldname,1) <> LEFT(UPPER(fieldname),1),true,false)
```

Comment: He wants to check for title case for every word in an arbitrary length string